# Solving an SDE in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation, stochastic

New to Wolfram Mathematica and I was wondering how to go about solving a stochastic differential equation.

```
   proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]n[
      t] == (b[t] - (0.5*(\[Sigma] ** 2))) {N - 
        n[t]}  \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] {N - 
        n[t]} \[DifferentialD]w[t], n[t], {n, 0.01}, t, 
   w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
```

This is the process I have defined, however when I include parameters and try to plot the results, I end up in error. I want to know how to solve it, and plot it in a graph.

Comment: numerous simple things wrong here. `**` is not an operator in mathematica.  `N` is not a legal variable name.

Comment: Yeah I am completely new to this. I have my equation and my model idea but I am struggling to translate it to mathematica. I keep getting errors when I try to solve it, I know I am inputting something wrong but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: fix those two things at least.  You also appear to be trying to use curly brackets for grouping things ( use parenthesis only ), and then I'd suggest asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cheers for the help!